# EmberJS, DS.Model, how to know if a particular attribute is dirty?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I can *monitor* the property [hasDirtyAttributes](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#property_hasDirtyAttributes) to know if any attribute is dirty.

How can I monitor if a specific attribute is dirty?

Something like:

```
attributeOneNeedSave: Ember.computed('attributeOne', function() {
  return this.get('dirtyAttributes.attributeOne');
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [changedAttributes](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_changedAttributes) method to discover if an attribute has changed. To turn it into a computed property, just call it when that property changes.

```
isNameDirty: Ember.computed('name', function() {
    const changedAttributes = this.changedAttributes();
    return !!changedAttributes.name;
})
```

Also, I'm not 100% sure if Ember Data will remove the property from `changedAttributes` if it changes back to it's original value. So it *might* be possible to get something like this:

```
const changedAttributes = {
    name: ['Bob', 'Bob']
};
```

If that's the case, check for equality as well.

```
isNameDirty: Ember.computed('name', function() {
    const changedAttributes = this.changedAttributes();
    if (!changedAttributes.name) {
        return false;
    }

    return (changedAttributes.name[0] !== changedAttributes.name[1]);
})
```

Comment: Beautiful. Ufff! finally something in the Ember API that actually has sense (for me) and is intuitive (for me) and has even more information that I need :).. I am a bit frustrated with the Ember learning curve ;)

Comment: The curve is quite steep. I would suggest getting familiar with the documentation and asking questions here when you get stuck. Also remember that if it's stupid but it works, it's not stupid. :) At this point just focus on getting things to work, you can make them fancy later.

Comment: I've edited the answer because looks like `changedAttributes()` is returning `ember$data$lib$system$empty$object$$EmptyObject` and it has not `hasOwnProperty()` function. Revert the changes if they have not sense for you. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: here you have a related issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35437395/316700 .. the initial beautifulness is diluting ;)