# EmberJs, changedAttributes() is not showing changes in the nested keys of a Hash attribute

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

The object is DS.Model:

```
$E.toString()
> "<reports-dashboard-client-app@model:report::ember596:914fc1b0-b14d-0133-bce2-68a86d03d830>"
```

The attribute is a Hash:

```
// app/models/report.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  filters: DS.attr(),
  ...
});
```

This is how it looks like now:

```
$E.get('filters')
> Object {__ember_meta__: Meta}
>   __ember_meta__: Meta
>   age_groups: (...)
>   get age_groups: GETTER_FUNCTION()
>   set age_groups: SETTER_FUNCTION(value)
>   genders: (...)
>   get genders: GETTER_FUNCTION()
>   set genders: SETTER_FUNCTION(value)
>   __proto__: Object
```

There is not any change in the Model:

```
$E.changedAttributes()
> ember$data$lib$system$empty$object$$EmptyObject {}
```

I modify one of the Hash keys but still not change in the Model:

```
$E.get('filters.age_groups')
> ["21-30", "31-40"]
$E.set('filters.age_groups', ["21-30"])
> ["21-30"]
$E.changedAttributes()
> ember$data$lib$system$empty$object$$EmptyObject {}
```

Only if I change the Hash it self I obtain a change in the Model:

```
$E.set('filters', {})
> Object {}
$E.changedAttributes()
> ember$data$lib$system$empty$object$$EmptyObject {filters: Array[2]}
```

What is curious is that I can *observe* the property `filters.age_groups` and the Observer is triggered properly when this key has a change.

How can I check if there is any change in the nested keys of DS.Model attribute which is a Hash?

Comment: an ember cannot observe arbitrary keys on nested hashes.. or arrays for that matter.  you need to define explicit observers (which you have shown).. or utilize some sort of object validaton such as: `ember-validations` addon.. or `ember-cp-validations` addon.

Comment: to elaborate a little further... the reason ember models are able to observe changes to typical `attrs` like they do.. is specifically because you have specifically defined keys in your model definition which provide the object map required to observe these changes... it breaks down when you go the step further and create a nested level.. with no defined attrs

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue recently, and I solved by using [Ember Fragments](https://github.com/lytics/ember-data-model-fragments).

You still needs to create model/fragments for each relationship, but the samples are quite easy to understand.

Please leave comments if you need help though.

**Update**

There's another way of solving to use [EmbeddedMixin](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.html)

Reference: http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/hasdirtyattributes-always-false-for-nested-properties/8534